# How to generate xml data from edifact data with c# code

Tags: edifact

I am new to edifact parsing.Could you please share sample code which converts edifact string to xml with c# code.I can't use third party libraries in my project.Please help with samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EdiFabric, you can use the good old XmlSerializer to write all the data out to an XML, [like this](https://github.com/EdiFabric/EDIFACT.NET/blob/master/EdiFabric.Examples.EDIFACT.XML/SerializeToXml.cs). BTW, I work for EdiFabric, so let me know if you have any questions related to the product.

Comment: Thank you Don Zoeggerle! EdiFabric- is this licensed software ? Will it capable of reading multiple invoice details from invoic file? Could you please share sample code.

Comment: Well, all software is licensed in one way or another, so yes it is licensed. If your question is whether it is paid software, then yes, it is paid software. Head to GitHub, [EDIFACT examples here](https://github.com/EdiFabric/EDIFACT.NET), and use the EdiFabric.Examples.EDIFACT.Demo project to parse any message type, version D96A. Use it with your sample/test files, by changing the path to your local files.